# e.keyCode==Keyboard.ESCAPE not working

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

i am building a flash game whereby when users select a building he/she wishes to build but later changes their mind, he/she could press the "ESC" on their keyboard so that the building gets unselected - users will not be forced to build once he/she selects a building. I tried assigning ESCAPE key but it did not work. it works fine if i assign it to SPACEBAR, LEFT, RIGHT KEY etc..but it does not make sense that users have to press those keys. ESCAPE key should be the ideal. Here's my code:

```
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, myKeyDown);
function myKeyDown(e:KeyboardEvent):void {
    if (e.keyCode==Keyboard.ESCAPE) {
        trace(e.keyCode);
        constructionButtonUnselected();
    }
}
```

Anybody knows whats preventing the system from recognizing the ESCAPE key?

Comment: Try tracing just before the if statement and see if the handler is called at all.

Comment: it traces any button except for esc key..

Comment: What happens when you hit Escape? Nothing, or something else?

Answer (score 4):

The escape key will work when a swf is running in a browser or standalone, but when you are running the content in Flash CS4 or Flash CS5, the IDE will trap the Escape key and not pass it on to the player. The same thing happens with the F# keys and a few others.

If you want to use the Escape key, you can, but you will need another key defined to use as a back up when you are working in the IDE.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, when you compile the SWF in the IDE, goto Controls -> Disable Keyboard Shortcuts, this will allow you to capture the Escape key's KeyboardEvent instead of the IDE grabbing it prematurely.

Answer (score 1):

i have tried the following code:

```
package{
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;


public class Esc extends Sprite{
    public function Esc(){
        addEventListener( Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onStage );

    }

    private function onStage( e:Event ):void {
        removeEventListener( e.type, onStage );
        stage.addEventListener( KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDown );

    }

    private function keyDown( e:KeyboardEvent ):void {

        out.text =  String( e.keyCode );
        out.text += ( "\n"+String( e.charCode ) );

        if  ( e.keyCode == Keyboard.ESCAPE ) {
            out.text = "Escape!";
        }
    }
}
```

}

out is a textfield on the stage.

i could see "Escape!"

While i was coding in flashCS4, compiled and tried, the FlashPlayer did not become Keyboard focus. After opening the swf in my browser it worked and gave me an Escape on the screen. But I know that the ESC-Key has some restrictions, just because it is the default key for leaving the full-screen mode and i think that if you are in Full-Screen mode there is no way to get this special keyboard event. Maybe if "allowfullscreen" is enabled in the params, this event is not longer under your control.